# Standard Deviation Given Only the Mean

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

A company that manufactures large LCD screens knows that not all pixels on their screen​ light, even if they spend great care when making them. In a sheet 6 ft by 12 ft that will be cut into smaller​ screens, they find an average of 5.7 blank pixels. They believe that the occurrences of blank pixels are independent.

What is the Standard Deviation of blank pixels / square foot?

I can't figure out how to calculate SD when only given the mean. the mean is 0.079 blank pixels per square foot

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show us your thoughts on the question.

Comment: I believe this question has insufficient information. If we knew how many pixels were in one square foot, or if we had any other way of figuring out that number, we would have enough information.

Comment: In the binomial distribution, if you know the number of trials and the mean then you can deduce the standard deviation. This is presumably a binomial distribution, but the number of trials isn't given.

Comment: Together, the assumption "They believe that the occurrences of blank pixels are independent" and the commonsense assumption that the total number of pixels per square foot is much greater than the average number of blank pixels per square foot suggest that the distribution of the number of blank pixels per square foot is governed approximately by a Poisson distribution, which are specified by a single parameter (e.g., the mean). For such distributions, the variance is equal to the mean.

Comment: @Travis That seems like an answer.

Comment: @DavidK I'll write a proper answer if OP indicates that that's likely what they're looking for. It's hard to tell without a little more context.

Comment: Travis's comment makes me think my first comment was too pessimistic. Mathematically, the variance of a binomial distribution is slightly smaller than the mean, but if the probability of individual failure is close enough to zero the mean and variance will be very close. One could assume $N$ pixels per square foot and see what comes out of that.

Answer (score 3):

Without any other information, it is not possible to deduce the Standard deviation from the mean alone. Presumably someone at the company has access to the data used to calculate the mean. That very same dataset should help you calculate all the stats that you need.